# .Net Connection to Bolt URI failing with Neo4jClient but not Neo4j.Driver

Tags: c#, docker, neo4j, neo4jclient, bolt

I have been connecting .Net Core code from within a Docker container to a Neo4j DB. I tried using Neo4jClient first but ran into issues with the http connection out of the docker container. I then tried the Neo4j.Driver directly with the bolt connection using host.docker.internal to alias localhost. This worked fine. I swapped back to Neo4jClient with bolt (again from within Docker) but its failing with.
Thanks for any help.

```
Neo4j.Driver.V1.ServiceUnavailableException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Connection with the server breaks due to SecurityException: Failed to establish encrypted connection with server bolt://host.docker.internal:7687/.
  Source=Neo4j.Driver
```

Update:
Following Chris Skardon's help below. I switched on ssl for bolt as per section Example 11.2. Enable Bolt SSL.
[As per instructions here at Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/ssl-framework/#term-ssl-certificate)

The code below using Neo4j.Driver directly works and updates the DB with 12 organisations.
Its running from within a .Net Core Docker container and using host.docker.internal. I would have expected this not to work without the Encryption config. But it does.

```
IDriver driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://host.docker.internal:7687", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "xxxxx"));
IAsyncSession session = driver.AsyncSession(o => o.WithDatabase("neo4j"));
```

This code using Neo4jClient doesn’t work.  I was originally running it within a docker container as above and thought that might be it. But still have a problem with no container

```
IDriver driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "xxxxx"), Config.Builder.WithEncryptionLevel(EncryptionLevel.Encrypted).ToConfig());
            var client = new BoltGraphClient(driver);
```

The exceptions are:

1. Connection with the server breaks due to SecurityException: Failed
   to establish encrypted connection with server
   bolt://localhost:7687/.'
2. IOException: Authentication failed because
       the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Nothing appears in the Neo4j logs. I don't have any specific code in the .Net Core API code for supporting SSL and googling the 2nd exception comes back with a lots of incorrect TLS results. So am exploring that.

Comment: What versions of the client/driver are you using? And what version of the DB?

Comment: Apologies should have provided. --
Neo4j 4.0.3 --
Neo4jClient 3.1.0.6 --
Docker Engine 19.03.8 --
.Net Core 3.1.101

Comment: I'm not at a computer at the moment, but can you try turning on encryption on the client and give it a whirl, I'm not sure of the syntax offhand, I'll put it properly when I get to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `4.x` versions of Neo4j require Encryption to be set, `Neo4jClient` doesn't actually provide an easy way to do this, so you'd need to pass in an `IDriver` instance, like so:

```
var driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "neo"), Config.Builder.WithEncryptionLevel(EncryptionLevel.None).ToConfig());
var client = new BoltGraphClient(driver);
```

**EDIT**

I've been testing this - and the problem is actually the opposite - you need to turn the encrpytion level to 'None' - unless you actually have an SSL cert setup

Comment: After a lot of googling, this was finally what worked. Even Neo4J's sample hello world application didn't work for local neo4j instance